# Why do iterable operations throw errors in Apache Beam functions?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm calling this function on an `Iterable` Java collection, resulting from a `GroupByKey` function:

```
static class FindCompleteOrder extends DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<Order>>, Order> {
    String COMPLETE_EVENT_NAME = "COMPLETE";

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        Iterable<Order> orders = c.element().getValue();
        boolean complete = false;

        do {
            try {
                Order order = orders.iterator().next();

                if (order.getEventName().equals(COMPLETE_EVENT_NAME)) {
                    complete = true;
                    order.setComplete(complete);
                    c.output(order);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        } while (complete == false && orders.iterator().hasNext());
    }
}
```

The function iterates a list of `Orders` and outputs the first instance that matches a specified `eventName` property. The loop ends if either the `Order` is found, or the entire collection has been iterated.

Random `Order` instances are generated upstream, and published to a **Pub/Sub** instance, at a rate of 2/second, where they are consumed by the **DataFlow** instance from which this function is called. Approx. 15 minutes into the operation, warnings begin to appear:

> Processing stuck in step Find Order for at least 15m00s without outputting or completing

The warning is issued as result of a sporadic failure in either `iterator().hasNext()`, or `iterator().next()`. The end result is that the entire pipeline stalls. The associated pipeline stage never emits output.

Replacing the loop with a standard for-loop solves the problem. However, doing so means iterating the entire collection; I would prefer to end the loop when an appropriate element is found, hence the do-while loop.

I'm interested to know why `iterator` operations cause the pipe to stall. FAIA the `Iterable` collection is immutable, and is not being modified by other processes.

I'm running **Java 8** and **Apache Beam 2.6** on **Windows**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `orders.iterator()` you are creating a *new* iterator, starting from the first order. This means you are processing the same order over and over again in the loop. Your call to `hasNext()` will always be true if there is more than one order. So, if you have more than one order or your first order doesn't set `complete` the loop will run forever, which is why you are hitting the timeout.

Instead you should call `iterator()` once and store the iterator instead of iterable, using that to loop:

```
static class FindCompleteOrder extends DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<Order>>, Order> {
    String COMPLETE_EVENT_NAME = "COMPLETE";

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        Iterator<Order> orders = c.element().getValue().iterator();
        boolean complete = false;

        do {
            try {
                Order order = orders.next();

                if (order.getEventName().equals(COMPLETE_EVENT_NAME)) {
                    complete = true;
                    order.setComplete(complete);
                    c.output(order);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        } while (complete == false && orders.hasNext());
    }
}
```